# How to use directive correctly with angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have trouble with using directive on my project. I am using angular 9.

Problem detail:

1. When element has rendered directive should be calcute position and set remaining height to the element.
2. Then change to other route then directive deosn't work.

Here is code sample:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[hasHeight]',
})
export class ListHeightDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setHeight();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.onResize();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize')
  onResize() {
    this.setHeight();
  }

  public setHeight() {
    const element = this.el.nativeElement;
    const topPos = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
      return;
    } else {
      const height = windowHeight - topPos - 60;
      element.style.height = height + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

And the first result goes well:

[image]

After i change current route to other then directive deosn't work what i want.

[image]

So, What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Comment: This is a pretty common requirement. I can suggest @angular/flex-layout for a simple solution.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is wrong on the 2nd picture? In what respect doesn't it work after you navigate?

Comment: @DanMacák yes after navigate the directive doesn't work.